# compiling custom c++ wrapper sqlite3

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, makefile, compilation

I've downloaded the sqlite3 source, and am trying to make a thin c++ wrapper to use sqlite3 in some of my applications. But I get a list of undefined references in sqlite3.c

In my database.hpp, I have the c include:
`extern "C" {`
`#include "sqlite3.h"`
`}`

My makefile looks like this:
`CC=gcc -g`
`CPP=g++ -g`
`CFLAGS=-c -Wall -ggdb`
`CPPSOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)`
`CSOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)`
`OBJECTS=$(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)`
`EXECUTABLE=testdb`
`all: $(CPPSOURCES) $(CSOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)`
`$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)`
`\t $(CPP)  $(OBJECTS) -o $@`
`.cpp.o:`
`\t $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) &< -o $@`
`.c.o:`
`\t $(CC) $(CFLAGS) &< -o $@`
`clean:`
`\t rm -rf *o $(EXECUTABLE)`

So what is missing in my Makefile? Or somewhere else .. Do I need some linker options?

tx,
aktiv

Comment: Please give some examples of the error messages you are seeing.

Comment: Tip:  make sure you are using the amalgamation version of SQLite when building http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the sqlite3 library or it won't work. I don't see any `-l` parameters.

Also, there's no need for you to use those .cpp.o and .c.o Makefile commands. They'll be handled by the built-in automatic rules. You just need to use the right flag variables. For C files you use CFLAGS, for C++ files you use CXXFLAGS, for the link step you provide LDFLAGS with your `-l` parameter.

Comment: Tx, but could you give me an example of the solution you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

On the download page there is a tarball with a makefile.

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070500.tar.gz

To create the library:

./configure --prefix /your/own/directory
make
make install

Whit this the "makefile" puts the headers and libs in that directory.

Then you can link like Zan explains.